# Environment variables for root user in VSCode Remote-Container

Tags: vscode-remote, remote-containers

I have a rather complex setup (corporate proxy) where I need to set proxies in the vscode remote container in order to do anything.
This works great if I set `HTTP_PROXY` and such in the `containerEnv` in `devcontainer.json`.

Now in case someone wants to temporarily add a tool via `apt`, one needs to use `sudo` in order to use `apt`. But the `root` user does not contain any of the environment variables passed in `containerEnv` or `remoteEnv` or even via `runArgs`.

This can be verified by running `sudo env` in the container which does not list any of the variables I set.

How can I set environment variables for the root user in the `devcontainer.json` file?